# DataTable distinct rows

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable with duplicate rows.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Id" });
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Name" });
DataRow datarow1 = dt.NewRow();
datarow1["Id"] = 1;
datarow1["Name"] = "George";
dt.Rows.Add(datarow1);
DataRow datarow2 = dt.NewRow();
datarow2["Id"] = 1;
datarow2["Name"] = "George";
dt.Rows.Add(datarow2);
DataRow datarow3 = dt.NewRow();
datarow3["Id"] = 3;
datarow3["Name"] = "David";
dt.Rows.Add(datarow3);
```

How to extract distinct rows from DataTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataTable getDistinctRows = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new string[] { "Id", "Name" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post a long while ago about this very same problem. I used LINQ and IEqualityComparer to solve this problem.

http://www.iramellor.com/LINQ-Distinct-a-DataTable-and-the-IEqualityComparerT

#### Update

Sorry I just saw the comment below. The URL above isn't working due to a site move. Here is the updated link:

https://iramellor.com/2008/08/26/LINQ-Distinct-a-DataTable-and-the-IEqualityComparer/

Comment: The page cannot be found